# the renderering of mapcanvas is still active

Tags: qgis, api, c++, zoom, mapcanvas

i am working with qgis c++ api 2.8.2 and qt4.8.5
i want to disable the rendering during zoom in or zoom out fonction in order to have a fast zoom
i try to use :

```
MyMapCanvas->stopRendering();
```

and

```
MyMapCanvas->setRenderFlag(false);
```

before the call of zoomIn ou zoomOut method but the renderer seems to be already active

how can i disable it before a zoomIn or zoomOut operation ?

Comment: QGIS is has multi threaded rednering.  It will handle that for you no need to start and stop the rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution
on the wheelevent of the mouse i do a zoomIn or a ZoomOut and i stop the rendereing and start a Qtimer to enable the rendering later, like 200ms, each time i move the wheel, the timer is started and the rendering was stopped
it allow to have a veryf fast zoomin and zoomout and when there is no action on the wheel the rendering is started

here is a sample of the code to illustrate :

```
void CMyQgsMapCanvas::wheelEvent( QWheelEvent* pevent)
{
    setRenderFlag(false);
    stopRendering();
    mTimeForRender.start(100);
    if ( pevent->delta() > 0 ) {
        MyzoomOut();
    }
    else {
        MyzoomIn();
    }
}
```

the slot :

```
void CMyQgsMapCanvas::StartTheRender()
{
    setRenderFlag(true);
    mTimeForRender.stop();
}
```

the connect

```
connect(&mTimeForRender,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(StartTheRender()));
```